# How to ignore some column when join tables in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Hello This is my 2 tables:

record and submission.

[image]

In submission, it has 1 composite primary key:(submission_id, question_id). One submission number can have several questions number. For example:

[image]

And as for record, it has a composite primary key:(student_id, exam_id). It looks like this:
[image]

I want to join these 2 tables like MySQL:

```sql
select * from record 
left join submission 
on record.submission_id = submission.submission_id.
```

[image]

But in hibernate, I have successfully join these 2 tables, but it gives me the following hql:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        ...all columns...
    from
        record record0_ 
    inner join
        submission submission1_ 
            on record0_.submission_id=submission1_.submission_id 
            and record0_.question_id=submission1_.question_id 
    where
        1=1
```

In this case, I will get 0 rows in the result.

I don't want it use "and record0_.question_id=submission1_.question_id" after on clause, because there is no question_id in my record table.

But I have to add all primary keys into the @joinColumns() when I add Submission attribute in Record class, like this:

```
// Record class

@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "record")
public class Record implements java.io.Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    // Other columns I don't need to show


    @Column(name = "submission_id")
    private Integer submissionId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "submission_id", referencedColumnName = "submission_id",insertable=false, updatable=false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "question_id", referencedColumnName = "question_id",insertable=false, updatable=false)
    })
    private Submission submission;
}
```

My Submission class like this:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name = "submission")
public class Submission implements java.io.Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "submission_id")
    private Integer submissionId;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "question_id")
    private Integer questionId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "submission")
    private Record record;

}
```

Anyone can give me some advice?

-------- How I combine these tables-------

Actually, I join 4 tables and all these joins have the same problem declared above.

Code below is how i combine these 4 tables (record, submission, question, optional)

```
@Override
    public List<RcdSubQuesOpt> getRcdSubQuesOpt(int studentID, int examId) {
        Session session = this.getSession();
        // RcdSubQuesOpt  --> this is a class to store attributes from different tables(classes)
        List<RcdSubQuesOpt> results;

        Transaction transaction = null;
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
        CriteriaQuery<RcdSubQuesOpt> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(RcdSubQuesOpt.class);
        
        // To combine these tables use join
        Root<Record> pRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Record.class);
        Join<Record, Submission> rcd2sub = pRoot.join(Record_.submission);
        Join<Submission, Question> sub2que = rcd2sub.join(Submission_.question);
        Join<Question, Optional> que2opt = sub2que.join(Question_.optional);

        // Attributes in RcdSubQuesOpt class
        // get these columns from result and assign them to RcdSubQuesOpt class
        criteriaQuery.multiselect(
                pRoot.get("studentId"),
                pRoot.get("examId"),
                rcd2sub.get("questionId"),
                rcd2sub.get("stuAnswer"),
                sub2que.get("content"),
                que2opt.get("content"),
                que2opt.get("answer"));


        // Predicate predicate = pRoot.get("examId").equals(1);
        criteriaQuery.where();

        results = session.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
        transaction.commit();

        return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned how you retrieve that data using hibernate. Have you tried trying to use @Query (select r from Record left join Submission sub on r.submissionId = sub.id where ...") ?

Comment: Thanks, I have add it.

Answer (score 0):

you have defined a @OneToOne relation in your record class. Apparantly thats wrong, since there exists more then one entry in your submission table for one record. So change this to @OneToMany and the respective relation in the submission class to @ManyToOne.

Besides your entities are not well named and mapped. Submission is in fact more of a question or an answer to it, because a line in that table does not represent one submission, which would be the expected meaning.